# XCode 8.1 - Unable to read module map content after "pod repo update"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I just updated my pods by `pod repo update`. After updating, I come back to Xcode to build my project. I am surprised that Xcode failed to build my project with errors like below:

```
error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support Files/KeychainSwift/KeychainSwift.modulemap': Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “KeychainSwift.modulemap” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/MyPath/MyPrj/Pods/Target Support Files/KeychainSwift/KeychainSwift.modulemap, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9f8530d330 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support Files/KeychainSwift/KeychainSwift.modulemap': Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “KeychainSwift.modulemap” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/MyPath/MyPrj/Pods/Target Support Files/KeychainSwift/KeychainSwift.modulemap, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9f847248e0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

(And many of my other pods...)

I did clean and rebuild but those do not help.

I don't know what's happening. How can I fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You may run the command line, and try to run `pod update` in the folder where `.xcworkspace` file located.